# "the trait is not implemented for Self" even though it totally is

Tags: rust

Look at this little snippet:

```
pub trait TestTrait {
    fn test_function(&self) {
        generic_function(self);
    }   
}

fn generic_function<T : TestTrait> (x : T) {
    //do something
}
```

This produces this error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Self: TestTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:10:26
   |
10 |         generic_function(self);
   |         ---------------- ^^^^ the trait `TestTrait` is not implemented for `&Self`
   |         |
   |         required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
note: required by a bound in `generic_function`
  --> src\main.rs:14:25
   |
14 | fn generic_function<T : TestTrait> (x : T) {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `generic_function`
```

But this doesn't make any sense. The `test function` is a method associated with the trait `TestTrait`. Of course, the self is going to implement this trait, that's the entire point!

What's going on? How to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`generic_function` takes an object by value. The function `test_function` gets a reference to `self` and does not own `self` so is not able to give `self` by value to `generic_function`.

There are 2 simple fixes. Note that both require the constraint `TestTrait where Self: Sized`.

1: `generic_function` takes the argument by reference

```rust
pub trait TestTrait where Self: Sized {
    fn test_function(&self) {
        generic_function(self);
    }   
}

fn generic_function<T : TestTrait> (x : &T) {
    //do something
}
```

2. `test_function` takes `self` by value

```rust
pub trait TestTrait where Self: Sized {
    fn test_function(self) {
        generic_function(self);
    }   
}

fn generic_function<T : TestTrait> (x : T) {
    //do something
}
```